# C++ function returning value as reference and return *this

Tags: c++

if I wanted to return "this" from a class member function as reference would this piece of code be correct ?

```
Record& operator=(const Record& that) {
    m_name = that.m_name;
    return *this;
}
```

Shouldn't i just use "return this" ?

Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yup, that's correct.

Return `this` wouldn't work since `this` is a pointer. (The reason it's a pointer and not a reference is because references weren't introduced into the language until after classes.)

In this specific case, if you're just going to assign the members anyway you shouldn't write a copy assignment operator; the default will do the same. When you manage some resource (and invoke the [Rule of Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29)), you'd want to use the [copy-and-swap idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29).

Comment: Perhaps a link would help 
http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Cpp/0180__Class/Returningthedereferencedthispointer.htm

Comment: Hence 'return this' would require 'Record*' as the return type in the declaration of the operator

Comment: @anijhaw: I don't see what for. :) And even if, I never particularity enjoyed that site. As far as I can tell, it's just code snippets. (And if I recall, some bad ones too.)

Comment: This is in the C++ FAQ: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/references.html#faq-8.4

Answer (score 4):

Your code is correct, but your comment `shouldn't I just use "return this"` is wrong (or, more accurately, the answer is "no, you shouldn't, and if you try, any compiler that works even halfway correctly compiler will stop you and give an error message.")

Given a class like:

```
class T { 
    void X() {}
    void Y() const {}
};
```

In `T::X`, `this` will have the type `T *const`, and in `T::Y`, `this` will have the type `T const *const`. Either way, it's a *pointer* to T, not a *reference* to T. To get a reference to T (for returning or any other purpose) you need to use `*this`.

Comment: (`this` not const-qualified, by the way. It is an rvalue, though.)

Comment: @GMan: right -- yet another oddity due to C++'s long and varied heritage. Back before you could overload `operator new` and `operator delete`, you got (kind of) the same effect by allocating a block of memory and assigning its value to `this` in the ctor. That's no longer allowed, but qualification to make that explicit has never been added...

Answer (score 1):

It may not matter for this specific case, but it is a good practice to have self assignment guard in the copy-assignment operator.

```
Record& operator=(const Record& that) {
    if( &that != this ) {
        m_name = that.m_name;
    }
    return *this;
}
```

This guards against statements like

```
Record r;
// do something with r
r = r;     // this is protected
```

It would be important when the class is doing some resource (e.g. dynamically allocated memory) management.

Comment: If the class were managing a resource, it should use the [copy-and-swap idiom](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom).